# Bar plot width inconsistency

Tags: python, matplotlib

please don't be too harsh.
Could someone explain me why the colors of bars in these two plots are so different?

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
plt.style.use('ggplot')

def plot3():
    bal=np.cumsum(ret)
    ind = np.arange(len(ret))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    barlist=ax.bar(ind,ret,label="Return")
    ax.plot(ind,bal,color='b',label="Balance")
    for i in ind:
        if ret[i]>=0:
            barlist[i].set_color('g')
        else:
            barlist[i].set_color('r')
    ax.legend(loc='best',frameon=False)
    plt.show()

def plot3b():
    bal=np.cumsum(ret)
    ind = np.arange(len(ret))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    colors=['g' if r>=0 else 'r' for r in ret]
    ax.bar(ind,ret,color=colors,label="Return")
    ax.plot(ind,bal,color='b',label="balance")
    ax.legend(loc='best',frameon=False)
    plt.show()
```

In my laptop given

```
n=100
ret=np.random.randn(n)
ret=np.insert(ret,0,0)
```

the plots are respectively

[image: plot3]

and

[image: plot3b]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bars have both `facecolor` and `edgecolor`, see the docs [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar).

It seems that `set_color()` sets *both* edge and face colour of the bar, so in your first chart the bars are wider that in your second, where the edge colour has not been set

If you change:
`ax.bar(ind,ret,color=colors,label="Return")`

To:
`ax.bar(ind,ret,color = colors, edgecolor = colors, label="Return")`

...then  both plots are the same:

**plot3()**
[image]

**plot3b()**
[image]

Please excuse the different spellings of color/colour in this post. Im in the UK, and it just feels wrong to spell colour without the 'u', so I've spelled it "my" way when not referencing a function argument.